# Add Javascript class to unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I added a Pusher javascript library to my `index.html` in the scripts.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pusher/4.2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>`

Now to use it in my component. I need to add this below the imports `declare var Pusher: any` and on my `ngOnInit` method I need to instantiate the class like this

`ngOnInit(){ this.pusher = new Pusher(key, {obj} )}`

The problem lies when I'm trying to unit test the component, this is the `beforeEach` function

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            HeaderComponent,
            SidebarComponent,
            SearchComponent,
            DashboardComponent,
            FooterComponent,
            LoginComponent,
            LogOutComponent,
            NoContentComponent,
            UnAuthorizedComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            RouterModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            CalendarModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {
                useHash: Boolean(history.pushState) === false,
                preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
              }),
        ],
        providers: [
            DoctorServices,
            AnnouncementService,
            LoginService,
            {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
        ]
    }).compileComponents();

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

and below is the my actual test

```
 it(`should be readily initialized`, () => {
    expect(fixture).toBeDefined();
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
});
```

everytime I run `npm run test:ci` I get a `Pusher is not defined error.` How do I deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you didn't add `pusher.min.js` in angular-cli or webpack.
You should pack it before you load it in `index.html`